# Error C2661 'fmt::v7::print': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments

Tags: c++, templates, fmt

I am trying to do :

```cpp
fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::red), "A critical error has occured. consult the logs and fix the issue! {0}", std::endl);
```

This results in the error message: `Error C2661 'fmt::v7::print': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments`.

Looking at the official documentation [here](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#terminal-color-and-text-style) shows the `fmt::print` as :

```cpp
 template <typename S, typename... Args>
void fmt::print(const text_style &ts, const S &format_str, const Args&... args)
```

which shows the number of arguments shouldn't be an issue, and in fact, it is not. If I replace `std::endl` with something as random as `1` instead, it compiles and builds just fine! What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a template, but template arguments can't be determined in this case, you have to specify them explicitly. e.g.

```
fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::red), 
           "A critical error has occured. consult the logs and fix the issue! {0}", 
           std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Technically correct, Filing under #unhelpfullyhelpful

Answer (score 3):

The error message is technically incorrect because there is an `fmt::print` overload that takes 3 arguments. However, even if you were able to pass `std::endl`, it wouldn't make sense because the flush would apply to the intermediate buffer, not when writing to `stdout`. You should use `\n` and call `fflush` instead:

```
fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::red),
           "A critical error has occured. consult the logs and fix the issue!\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Note that passing template arguments explicitly won't work - you'll just get a different error: https://godbolt.org/z/T3GYqdchb.